# How to store mac address

Tags: android-studio, mac-address

I'm writing an App with login and register, it works but I want to add something. Is it possible, when a user register his datas, to get directly from his phone the Mac Address and store it together the other datas?

For example, he has to insert name, user, password and email, when he clicks on register in the database there are all this datas and the macaddress of his phone too.

This is my RegisterActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by amardeep on 10/26/2017.
 */

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaration EditTexts
    EditText editTextUserName;
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    //Declaration TextInputLayout
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutUserName;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    //Declaration Button
    Button buttonRegister;

    //Declaration SqliteHelper
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        initTextViewLogin();
        initViews();
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()) {
                    String UserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    //Check in the database is there any user associated with  this email
                    if (!sqliteHelper.isEmailExists(Email)) {

                        //Email does not exist now add new user to database
                        sqliteHelper.addUser(new User(null, UserName, Email, Password));
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User created successfully! Please Login ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else {

                        //Email exists with email input provided so show error user already exist
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User already exists with same email ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            }
        });
    }

    //this method used to set Login TextView click event
    private void initTextViewLogin() {
        TextView textViewLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
        textViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    //this method is used to connect XML views to its Objects
    private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
        textInputLayoutUserName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutUserName);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    }

    //This method is used to validate input given by user
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Get values from EditText fields
        String UserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //Handling validation for UserName field
        if (UserName.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutUserName.setError("Please enter valid username!");
        } else {
            if (UserName.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutUserName.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutUserName.setError("Username is to short!");
            }
        }

        //Handling validation for Email field
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError("Please enter valid email!");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
        }

        //Handling validation for Password field
        if (Password.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Please enter valid password!");
        } else {
            if (Password.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Password is to short!");
            }
        }


        return valid;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you already tried ? What's exactly the problem ?

Comment: I still haven't tried anything, I'm trying to understand how can I store the Macaddress of the phone directly at the registration. I never did that and I'd like to know how to proceed. I didn't find anything similar in Internet, I found a code only to show the Macaddress but I don't need to show it, I need to save it in the same database with the datas of the user